# Using joins, having and where in console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I'm inside the rails console trying to find all users with more than one order that have the state "completed".

This line gives me all the users with more than 1 order generally, whether or not the state of the order is completed, refunded or errored:

```
User.joins(:orders).group("users.id").having("count(orders)>1")
```

Im trying to get something like this:

```
User.joins(:orders).group("users.id").having("count(orders.where(state: "completed"))>1")
```

This is my first time using joins and having, and I'm confused why this is not working, and I've been searching this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
User.joins(:orders).where(orders: {state: "completed"}).group("users.id").having("count(orders)>1")
```